# Get next element with PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I received a very weird XML file to process.

Instead of grouping names with group tags, like this:

```
<data>
    <group>
        <name>John</name>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <name>Susan</name>
    </group>
    <group>
        <name>Cesar</name>
        <name>Joseph</name>
        <name>Sylvia</name>
        <name>Steve</name>
    </group>
</data>
```

It inserts a separator tag after each element, like this:

```
<data>
    <name>John</name>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <name>Mary</name>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <name>Susan</name>
    <separator>;</separator>
    <name>Cesar</name>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <name>Joseph</name>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <name>Sylvia</name>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <name>Steve</name>
    <separator>.</separator>
</data>
```

";" and "." are the group delimiters. (I know, that's weird, but I can't change that and I have to process a lot of these files)

To get all names and all separators I can use the following code:

```
$data = <<<XML
    <data>
        <name>John</name>
        <separator>,</separator>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <separator>,</separator>
        <name>Susan</name>
        <separator>;</separator>
        <name>Cesar</name>
        <separator>,</separator>
        <name>Joseph</name>
        <separator>,</separator>
        <name>Sylvia</name>
        <separator>,</separator>
        <name>Steve</name>
        <separator>.</separator>
    </data>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach ($xml->name as $name){
    echo "$name\n";
}

foreach ($xml->separator as $sep){
    echo "$sep\n";
}
```

But this way, I can't get the name and the correspondent separator on a single loop.

Is there any way to know, on the first loop, the next element of each name?

Comment: This is a good example of a well asked question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the XML like this and build an `array`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);

foreach ($xml->children() as $name => $value) {

    if ($name == 'name') $names[$i][] = (string)$value;
    elseif ($name == 'separator' && $value == ';') $i++;

}
```

Output `$names`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>array(3) {
    [0]=>string(4) "John"
    [1]=>string(4) "Mary"
    [2]=>string(5) "Susan"
  }
  [1]=>array(4) {
    [0]=>string(5) "Cesar"
    [1]=>string(6) "Joseph"
    [2]=>string(6) "Sylvia"
    [3]=>string(5) "Steve"
  }
}
```

You can then just pick the names from the array.

see it working: https://eval.in/95853

Answer (score 3):

I hope that i understand your question.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$i = 0;
$res = '';
foreach ($xml->name as $name){
    $res .= "$name ".$xml->separator[$i];
    $i++;
}
$groups = explode(';',$res);
```

Comment: I think you have to put another explode, to separate the commas for each group. `$g = array(); foreach ($groups as $group) { $g[] = explode(',', $group); }`. Also, the name cannot have a ";" or a "," inside. But this is a way to solve the problem. Thanks.